# Don't focus Python subprocess, linux

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, x11

I'm running a script in a console to help me in a repetitive task.
I want open image in gallery and write down numbers from an image.

```
feh = subprocess.Popen(['feh', 'tmp.jpg'])

print ("Input number from image:")
number = input()

feh.kill()
```

This code works, but window managers keep focusing `feh`, which adds an additional step of refocusing console window. Is there an additional argument I can pass to prevent this behavior or another way around?

Comment: Does the Python script you're running have its own window? If so, with which widget set / graphical toolkit?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, the OP says the script is running in a console, by which I'm assuming, since this is Linux and X11, that we're actually talking about a terminal window.

Answer (score 3):

One dirty workaround is to simply refocus window by mouse.

I used `xdotool`

```
feh = subprocess.Popen(['feh', 'tmp.jpg'])

time.sleep(0.1)
subprocess.call(['xdotool', 'click', '1'])

something = input()

feh.kill()
```

Comment: Using `windowactivate` or `windowfocus` instead of `click` is probably better. Alternatively, if you know the window ID you could also do `wmctrl -i -a <winid>`.

Answer (score 3):

Python has native GUI modules, named [tkinter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter).

GUI program can be terrifyingly easy to write, if it is python.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2 -i
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import *
import os

files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if f.endswith(".png")]

root = Tk()
label = Label(root)
label.pack()

for name in files:
    im = PhotoImage(file=name)
    label.config(image=im)
    print("your number plz")
    input_str = raw_input()
```